# `Where` clause returns empty list even if the logic test is `true`

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, where-clause, caliburn.micro

I need to display items satisfying some conditions.

```
public BindableCollection<BaseTreeItemViewModel> TreeItems
{
    get
    {
        if (_logicTest)
            return (BindableCollection<BaseTreeItemViewModel>)_treeItems.Where(n => _logicTest);
        else
            return _treeItems;
    }
    set
    {
        _treeItems = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TreeItems);
    }
}
```

In fact in `Where` clause there will be different test (`n.Header == "ABC"`), but it is not working even for `_logicTest`, which we know is `true` while launching the line with `Where`.

`_treeItems` contains about 20 elements and for `_logicTest=false` they are all returned. On the other hand for `_logicTest=true` function returns empty collection.

Where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit**

As @Robert.S [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156434/where-clause-returns-empty-list-even-if-the-logic-test-is-true/42156550#comment71483925_42156550) , I've used:

```
return new BindableCollection<BaseTreeItemViewModel>(_treeItems.Where(n => _logicTest));
```

and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `_logicTest`? A property? If so it might change while the collection is evaluated. Moreover the return value of `Where` is an `IEnumerable<T>`. The real values will only be evaluated if you use the collection (e.g. in a foreach loop).

You can try to add a `ToList()` or `ToArray()` at the end of the `Where`. This way the collection is evaluated immediately and you can see if there are really no items at the point of time when the getter is executed.

Another option is the VS debugger. In the watch table you can evaluate the collection with the small refresh icon. This way you also can see the "real" items.

But if you use the collection later (e.g. in a foreach loop) and `_logicTest` is not true anymore, the collection may be empty.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Program
{
    static bool _logicTest = false;
    static int[] items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _logicTest = true;

        var foo = items.Where(n => _logicTest);

        _logicTest = false;

        Console.WriteLine(foo.Count());

        _logicTest = true;

        Console.WriteLine(foo.Count());
    }
}
```

The output will be:
0
3

In the above example `Count()` will evaluate the collection to determine its size. You can see that the value of `_logicTest` is evaluated at this very moment and not when `Where` was called.

A possible workaround for your case would be a local variable:

```
get
{
    bool logicTest = _logicTest;

    if (logicTest)
        return (BindableCollection<BaseTreeItemViewModel>)_treeItems.Where(n => logicTest);
    else
        return _treeItems;
}
```

The local variable will not change. But you should store the property value in another variable. Cause if you access the property when `_logicTest` is false, you will run into the same problem of course.

Here is the above example with the workaround:

```
class Program
{
    static bool _logicTest = false;
    static int[] items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _logicTest = true;

        var foo = items.Where(n => _logicTest);
        var bar = Items;

        _logicTest = false;

        Console.WriteLine(foo.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Count());

        _logicTest = true;

        Console.WriteLine(foo.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Count());
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Items
    {
        get
        {
            bool logicTest = _logicTest;

            return items.Where(n => logicTest);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is 0 3 3 3

Comment: `_logicTest` is boolean variable, there is no way it can change while evaluation. 'BindableCollection<T>' inherits from 'IEnumerable<T>'. `ToList` or `ToArray` is not working - problem with conversion of types.

Comment: Try to append `Count()` then and see if it is 0 inside the getter.

Comment: My problem is that is not working even if I try `Where(n => true)`.

Comment: Have you checked that `_treeItems` is not empty?

Comment: Yes. `_treeItems`  contains 20 elements.

Comment: So the following code will return true? `if (_treeItems.Count() != _treeItems.Where(n => true).Count())`. Can you test this please?

Comment: Yes. These two values are different.

Comment: This is strange indeed. My only guess is that the class `BindableCollection<T>` comes with its own `Where`-method which acts different or it causes some strange side effects in its enumeration logic. Where comes this class from?

Comment: `Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection<T>`. As I can see, it inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` and there is no override for 'Where()'

Comment: Maybe casting to `BindableCollection<BaseTreeItemViewModel>` is the problem? `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. This is not a `BindableCollection<BaseTreeItemViewModel>`. You can't just cast it. You have to use the constructor to create a new collection like `new BindableCollection<BaseTreeItemViewModel>(...Where(...))`.